# Problems with paging in vuex store/actions [this.paginator is not a function]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, pagination

I am trying to solve a problem when I call the paginator function in [ACTYPE.GET_MOVIES].

It shows me the error that says the following:

> TypeError: _this.paginator is not a function at eval (actions.js?
>   63e0: 13)

**Store/Actions.js**

```
import {ACTYPE} from './types/actions_types';
import {MUTYPE} from './types/mutations_types';
import {BASE_URL , TOP_MOVIES , QUERY_URL} from '../API_URLs/index';
import axios from 'axios';

const A = axios.create({ baseURL: String(BASE_URL) });

export const actions = {
  [ACTYPE.GET_MOVIES]({commit} , page){
  A.get(TOP_MOVIES).then((res) =>{
    console.log(res);
    const dataPaginated = this.paginator(res.data , page)
    commit(MUTYPE.SET_MOVIES_DATA , dataPaginated);
    commit(MUTYPE.IS_LOADING , false);
  }).catch((err) =>{
      console.log(err);
  });  
}, 

paginator(items, page, per_page){
  var page = page || 1,
  per_page = per_page || 10,
  offset = (page - 1) * per_page,

  paginatedItems = items.slice(offset).slice(0, per_page),

  total_pages = Math.ceil(items.length / per_page),

  paginContent = {
    page: page,
    per_page: per_page,
    pre_page: page - 1 ? page - 1 : null,
    next_page: (total_pages > page) ? page + 1 : null,
    total: items.length,
    total_pages: total_pages,
    data: paginatedItems
  };
  console.log("Paginate Item: " , paginatedItems);
  console.log("Pagin Content: " , paginContent);
  return paginContent.data;
 },
```

Comment: your paginator function is defined with 3 parameters you are calling it passing two... perhaps this is the problem ? here: `const dataPaginated = this.paginator(res.data , page)`

Comment: Yes, the problem is that liine

Comment: So were you able to solve it adding a third parameter ? If so, should I add an answer for you or will you delete this question ?

Comment: The error continues,

Actually it is not necessary to have to pass the other two parameters. Just enough to pass an array as a parameter.

Comment: @JorgeCampos What I want to do is in the Home.vue to make the call of
  this. $ store.dispatch (ACTYPE.GET_MOVIES, this.page);

But he keeps showing me the same error in the file store / actions.js

Comment: Have you tried removing the `this.`  from the paginator call?

Comment: Yes, but still with the same error.

Comment: If I add a point after the pagination function it shows me two options.
a then () or catch ()

Answer (score 1):

you should change your `paginator(items, page, per_page){ ...`

to `function paginator(items, page, per_page){`

That way the declaration gets hoisted. If not `paginator` is not declared.

then you can remove the `this` in `this.paginator(res.data , page)`

After doing that it should work

Comment: I modified the code using function paginator (items, page, per_page) {..} but it shows me a syntax error, I changed it paginator: function (items, page, per_page) but it shows me the error of ReferenceError: paginator is not defined

Comment: my bad, I didnt realise that paginator was inside the actions.  I would place it outside of the actions object since its not an action. Then the rest should work (using the answer provided before)